# User control instances are null while using nested master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have couple of user controls which are statically referenced in aspx. We are setting some public properties on the user controls in Page_Preinit event.
The page also references a master page

This was working fine so far. Had to do a ui redesign and we implemented nested master pages.

Now, all of a sudden, the user controls are showing up as null. If I change the master page to parent one (instead of child -nested), it works fine.

Appreciate any pointers to this issue.

some sample code: here ucAddress is null

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) { ucAddress.City = "Dallas"; }
```

Comment: Found the issue. had to initialize child master page before accessing user control. `MasterPage master = (MasterPage)this.Master.Master;`

Comment: I'm running into this same issue and I wish you provided a complete answer that I could learn from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue. had to initialize child master page before accessing user control.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](https://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2008/12/20/accessing-aspnet-page-controls-during-preinit/) describes the problem very well and also offers a solution. I can confirm that the solution works and I'll repeat the relevant parts here:

**The problem**

We have a user control and initialize its control in the `Init` event so that it is ready when the `ViewState` is restored (between `Init` and `Load`).

> Once you start using this encapsulation technique, it won’t be long until you want to pass in a parameter that affects the data you load. Before we do, we need to be aware that the `Init` event is fired in reverse order. That is, the child controls have their `Init` event fired before that event is fired at the parent. As such, the `Page.Init` event is too late for us to set any properties on the controls.
>
> The natural solution is to try and use the `Page.PreInit` event, however when you do you’ll often find that your control references are all `null`. This happens when your page is implemented using a master page, and it relates to how master pages are implemented. The `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder />` controls in a master page use the `ITemplate` interface to build their contents. This content (child controls) is not usually prepared until the `Init` event is called, which means the control references are not available. For us, this represents a problem.

**The Solution**

> The fix is remarkably simple; all we need to do is touch the `Master` property on our `Page` and it will cause the controls to become available. If we are using nested master pages, we need to touch each master page in the chain.

The author of the blog post then offers a nice little snippet that you can execute in the `PreInit` handler of your `Page` that uses a `MasterPage` and contains a user control:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    // Walk up the master page chain and tickle the getter on each one
    MasterPage master = this.Master;
    while( master != null ) master = master.Master;
    
    // Access now initialized user control
    ucAddress.City = "Dallas";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It worked like Magic. I find myself having to do workarounds way too often with Web Forms. Looking to learn a more modern tool that hopefully is not as inconvenient.